# example of $\lambda$ that is not $\sigma$-finite

Tags: real-analysis

why  $\lambda$ is not $\sigma$-finite. in the following measure space?

$\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathscr{F}=\{A:A\subset\mathbb{R}\}$ and $\mu$ is the counting measure. $f:=1$. Then

$$\lambda (A)=\int_{A}f\, d\mu$$

$$\lambda(A)=\operatorname{card}(A).$$

Definition of $\sigma$-finite: A non-negative finitely additive set function $\mu$ on a field $F$ is said to be $\sigma$-finite on $F$ iff $\Omega$  can be written as $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}$ where $A_{n}$ belong to $F$  and $\mu(A_{n})<\infty$ for all $n$

Comment: What are the sets of finite measure here?

Answer (score 1):

We have $\lambda(\{x\})=1$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus any set of finite $\lambda$ measure is finite, and any union of countably many such sets is countable. So no uncountable set can be written as a countable union of sets of finite measure.